# Нужно упростить конструкцию if в python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, if

```py
x = int(input ('Введите число:'))
if x :
   pass
else:
   print('Число ровно нулю')
```

Comment: `if x == 0: print('Число равно нулю')`.

Comment: не "ровно", а "равно". а что выбудете делать, если x == None?

Comment: `if not x: print('Число равно нулю')`

Comment: @strawdog так x вводится пользователем, потом еще и в целое число конвертируется. Тут он никогда не будет  None

Answer (score 2):

```
x = int(input ('Введите число:'))
if not x:
   print('Число ровно нулю')
```